# How to add Intellisoftware library to a Java application?

Tags: java, import

I am trying to develop a Java application that can send an SMS to my mobile. I have found [Intellisoftware](https://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/sms-gateway/java-sdk/) and I downloaded the SDK. The SDK is in zipped folder so I have added it the way we do a .jar file but one class is not showing -`IntelliSMS`. How do I add this SDK to my project so that my project runs successfully?

Below is the sample code that I have used:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] argx) {

    IntelliSMS objIntelliSMS = new IntelliSMS();
    objIntelliSMS.Username = "MyUsername";
    objIntelliSMS.Password = "MyPassword";

    objIntelliSMS.SendMessage("mynumber", "Hello", "SENDER_ID");

   }

}
```

Below is a screen shot showing the imported files:

[image]

Comment: Buildpath --> Add library

Comment: Okay, which one do I select for a zip folder since there are may options after clicking Add Library? I am using Eclipse luna